# Is it safe to Drive an hour or more on the highway after a brake pad change?

Tags: brakes, brake-pad

So I recently replaced the brakes pads on my Vehicle. After I did the change I drove it around my Neighborhood for a short time. I got back to my garage and the Rotors were super hot. Which I have done pad changes before and the rotors always seem to get hot during the break in process from Pads to Rotors. But how long does it last? (The brake in process) and Would it be safe to drive an hour or more the next day on the Highway (70+MPH) after replacing the pads??

Comment: I would either say the calipers piston is stuck or it wasnt properly cleaned from rust/brake dust. At least according to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Perfectly safe, if the brake job was done correctly. Heat is fine - the pads will be burning off the anti-rust coating.

Remember to bed the pads in correctly; the following content is not mine, it's from http://brakeperformance.com/bedding-in-rotors.php

- Perform 3-4 medium stops from 45mph. Slightly more aggressive than
  normal braking. You don't need to come to a complete stop for each
  pass. This brings the brake rotors up to temperature so they are not
  exposed to sudden thermal shock.
- Make 8-10 aggressive stops from 60mph down to 15mph. For this set of
  semi-stops, you want to be firm and aggressive, but not to the point
  where ABS activates and the wheels lock up. It's important to note
  that you don't come to a complete stop but rather a semi-stop
  (~15mph). Accelerate back up to 60mph as soon as you slowed down to
  your semi-stop.
- The brake pads and brake rotors are extremely hot at this point and
  sitting on one point will imprint the pad material onto the surface
  unevenly. This can cause vibration and uneven braking.
- You may notice that your brakes will start fading, and sometimes
  smoke, after the 6th or 7th pass. This fade will stabilize and will
  gradually recess once your brakes have cooled down to normal
  operating temperatures. Drive carefully as your brakes may feel
  softer for the next few minutes.
- Try not to come to a complete stop and find a stretch of road where
  you can coast for 5-10 minutes, preferably without using your brakes.

Comment: ok back from driving around for about 30mins. Did what you said. Noticed some smoking but prob. Normal. New Question tho. Have lack of pressure in the brake pedal and I hear a squeaking noise coming from my Drive side front caliper when i press on the brake. I hear no rubbing or grinding noise from the pads and Rotors the whole time I was driving around also.

Comment: Sounds like the calipers may be dragging slightly.  Strip them (when they've cooled) and debur and lubricate the slides then reassemble.  Remember, new pads will force the caliper to use parts of the slide that haven't been used in quite a while.